# LibreSSL 3.0.2 compile error on Solaris 10 : undefined reference to symbol 'SHA512Final'

Tags: compiler-errors, linker-errors, solaris, libressl

We are trying to compile LibreSSSL 3.0.2 on Solaris 10. We are using the GNU gcc 4.6.2 and have the following problem:

```
Making all in tests
make[1]: Entering directory `/users/login/e486530/openssh81/libressl-3.0.2/tests'
CCLD     handshake_table
/soft/gnu/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/4.6.2/../../../../i386-pc-solaris2.10/bin/ld: /users/login/e486530/openssh81/libressl-3.0.2/crypto/.libs/libcrypto.a(getentropy_solaris.o): undefined reference to symbol 'SHA512Final'
/soft/gnu/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/4.6.2/../../../../i386-pc-solaris2.10/bin/ld: note: 'SHA512Final' is defined in DSO /lib/libmd.so.1 so try adding it to the linker command line
/lib/libmd.so.1: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The error is **"undefined reference to symbol 'SHA512Final"**

The proposition made is *'SHA512Final' is defined in DSO /lib/libmd.so.1 so try adding it to the linker command line*. But just after we have the error **"/lib/libmd.so.1: could not read symbols: Invalid operation"** so apparently the compiler is trying already to read symbols from this library without succèss.

Any idea to compile LibreSSL on Solaris with succes?

---

I add some details ...

The compilation is made on Solaris 10 for **i386** with the GNU gcc compiler 4.6.2. I don't 'set the bits for compilation.

The GNU gcc shows the following information with the option -v

```
$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/soft/gnu/bin/gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/soft/gnu/libexec/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/4.6.2/lto-wrapper
Target: i386-pc-solaris2.10
Configured with: ../gcc-4.6.2/configure --prefix=/soft/gnu --with-gnu-ld --with-gnu-as --with-gmp=/soft/gnu --with-mpc=/soft/gnu --with-mpfr=/soft/gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.6.2 (GCC)
```

And the uname -a option shows:

```
$ uname -a
SunOS yvas0pd0 5.10 Generic_150401-30 i86pc i386 i86pc
```

I have just recompiled with the flags:

```
CC="gcc -m64"
CXX="g++ -m64"
```

And the error is now

```
/soft/gnu/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/4.6.2/../../../../i386-pc-solaris2.10/bin/ld: /users/login/e486530/openssh81/libressl-3.0.2/crypto/.libs/libcrypto.a(getentropy_solaris.o): undefined reference to symbol 'SHA512Final'
/soft/gnu/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/4.6.2/../../../../i386-pc-solaris2.10/bin/ld: note: 'SHA512Final' is defined in DSO /lib/amd64/libmd.so.1 so try adding it to the linker command line
/lib/amd64/libmd.so.1: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
```

So the library used now is a 64 bit library but the problem remains ... :-|

Hope it helps. For the moment we are going to use OpenSSL 1.1.1, which compiles succesfully.

Regards

Comment: Are you doing a 64-bit compile?  Because `/lib/libmd.so.1` is a 32-bit library.

Comment: The compilation is made on Solaris 10 for **i386** with the GNU gcc compiler 4.6.2. I don't 'set the bits for compilation.

Comment: I have just added new details for the compilation.

Comment: OK, there's definitely something strange going on.  The "invalid operation" is likely because some system call related to `libmd.so.1` in some way returned `EINVAL`.  The problem is figuring out what system call failed before you can know why it failed and how to fix it.  If you run your make process under `truss` you should be able to identify the failed call:  `truss -f -a -vall -w2 -o /path/to/output/file [normal make command]` will give you the information - somewhere.  That output file will be large, but near the end will be a system call that failed with `EINVAL`

Comment: (cont)  That failed system call will almost certainly be right before the error message is emitted.  You should be able to find that error message by searching for `/ l i b / a m d 6 4 / l i b m d . s o . 1 :` in the output file.  Note the spaces in the string - `truss` output adds an extra space so non-printable character values can be printed as two-byte hex values in the output.  Somewhere above that error message being written will be a system call that failed with the `EINVAL` value.  That failed call is what's causing your build to fail.

Comment: (cont) How old is your system?  If it's an older CPU, both `libmd.so.1` libraries may be compiled to use an instruction set that your CPU does not support.  That is one of the few things that I can think of right now that might result in an "invalid operation" failure when trying to load a shared object on Solaris.

Comment: You can also run `elfdump /lib/libmd.so.1` and compare its output to something that must be working, like `elfdump /lib/libc.so`, especially the header information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error shown in the compilation

```
'SHA512Final' is defined in DSO /lib/amd64/libmd.so.1 so try adding it to the linker command line
/lib/amd64/libmd.so.1: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
```

Means really that the file /lib/amd64/libmd.so.1 is not being used by the linker. I have misunderstood the real meaning.

So, **adding -lmd to the LDFLAGS variable makes the compilation finish**

For information, the full content for the LDFLAGS variable used in my compilation is the following:

export LDFLAGS="-Wl,-disable-new-dtags,-rpath=/opt/openssh-8.1/lib,-lmd"